# Usage Marionette.module with AMD

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I want to use in my new project Coffee + Marionette + Require.js,
but i have a problem with module loadings query. Module will started after main app starting callback;

```
# main.coffee  
require.config
    paths:
        # ... 
        app: '/js/app/app'
        marionette: '/js/vendors/backbone.marionette'
    shim:
        # ...
        'marionette':
            deps: ['backbone']
            exports: 'Marionette'
        'app':
            deps: ['marionette']
            exports: 'App'


require ['app'], (App) ->
    App.start()


# module.coffee
define ['app'], (App) ->
    MyModule = App.module('MyModule');
    MyModule.foo = ->
        console.log 'bar'
    return MyModule


# app.coffee
define (require) ->
    App = new Marionette.Application
    App.addInitializer ->
        require 'module'
        console.log 'App inited'

    App.on
        'start': ->
            console.log 'App started'

    return App


# Output
App inited
App started
Module inited
```

How must i define the module, if i want to use him in initializers ?

Answer (score 0):

Marionette module system is meant to be a simple alternative for require.js. I would discourage from using both together because you will run into circular dependencies issues all the time, especially if you want to have a "one class per file" organisation. Note that requirejs gives you all what marionette modules does + much, much more (async loading, project building etc.).

Some more reading from Marionette documentation

- https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/AMD-Modules-vs-Marionette%27s-Modules
- https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs